# FTP python powered server

Tags: python, ftp

as a python newbie I wanted to play around and create an FTP connection between my two computers. (one as a client, and one as a server). every thing works great, but only if I use them both on the same network with local IP addresses, my question is: How can I use my computer as an FTP server and access him with the other one over different networks? (using public IP addresses)

code on my server computer:

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("username", "password", "C:\\Users\\someone\\somewhere\\FTP", perm="rl")     

handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
server = FTPServer(("192.162.1.101", 21), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

and the code I use to fetch the file:

```
import ftplib
import shutil

def download (ftp, directory, file):
f = open(file,"wb")
data = ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" % file,f.write)
f = open(file, "r")
shutil.copy2(f,"D:\\Users\\user-pc\\Desktop")
f.close()


ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.162.1.101","username", "password")

download(ftp, "FTP", "1.jpg")
raw_input()
```

Comment: As Burhan said, your code looks okay.  You need to forward the appropriate FTP ports on your router.  Seek help here: http://portforward.com/  This website has a list of routers, find yours and follow the instructions to forward the port.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Python related. You need to forward a port (pick any port above 1024) from your router to port `21` on `192.162.1.101`; then connect your client to the public IP provided by your ISP.